# access to array outside function

Tags: php, arrays, function

Have found 2 threads on this here at Stackoverflow, hovever these are about how to return an array. I can generate an array inside the function and it is having the right content, however when doing var_dumping of $target_file outside the function it is NULL. Otherwise the code is doing what it is supposed to do. 
Is it a scope thing? or...have I done something completely wrong here? 
Can anyone please help me access the returned array outside the function?

```
function copy_files3($requested, $src_path, $send_path){
//function copy_files renames and copies pdf-files to a specific folder. 
//ARRAY $requested (keys INT), (names STR) holds the names of the selected files
//STR $src_path is the full path to the requested files
//STR $send_path is the full path to the re-named files
//ARRAY $target_file holds the names of the renamed files
    $i=0;
    $target_file = array();
    $src_filename = array();
    $b=array();
    foreach($requested as $value) {
        //$value holds the names of the selected files. 
        //1 Expand to get the full path to the source file
        //2 Generate a 10 char + .pdf (aka 14 char) long new file name for the file.
        //3 Generate full path to the new file.
        $src_filename[$i] = $src_path.$value;
        $rnam[$i] = randomstring(); //function randomstring returns a 10 char long random string
        $target_file[$i] = $send_path.$rnam[$i].'.pdf';
        echo 'target_file['.$i.'] = '.$target_file[$i].'<br>';
        copy($src_filename[$i],$target_file[$i]);
        $i++;
    }
    return($target_file);
}
```

I have files renamed and placed in the correct folders on my server, the only problem is accessing the $target_file array after this function.

Comment: Please show the code where you call the function, and try and use the returned value

Answer (score 5):

`$target_file` exists only inside the function. And yes, it's a scope thing.

You are returning this variable's **value**, but **not** the variable itself.

All you have to do is to assign returned value to some variable while invoking the function.

```
$returnedValue = copy_files3($requested, $src_path, $send_path);
```

Now, `$returnedValue` has the same value as `$target_file` had inside the function.

Comment: Super, of course - always nice to have others look at your stupid mistakes. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 

function copy_files3($requested, $src_path, $send_path){
//function copy_files renames and copies pdf-files to a specific folder. 
//ARRAY $requested (keys INT), (names STR) holds the names of the selected files
//STR $src_path is the full path to the requested files
//STR $send_path is the full path to the re-named files
//ARRAY $target_file holds the names of the renamed files
    $i=0;
    $target_file = array();
    $src_filename = array();
    $b=array();
    foreach($requested as $value) {
        //$value holds the names of the selected files. 
        //1 Expand to get the full path to the source file
        //2 Generate a 10 char + .pdf (aka 14 char) long new file name for the file.
        //3 Generate full path to the new file.
        $src_filename[$i] = $src_path.$value;
        $rnam[$i] = randomstring(); //function randomstring returns a 10 char long random string
        $target_file[$i] = $send_path.$rnam[$i].'.pdf';
        echo 'target_file['.$i.'] = '.$target_file[$i].'<br>';
        copy($src_filename[$i],$target_file[$i]);
        $i++;
    }
    return($target_file);
} 

$returnedValue = copy_files3($requested, $src_path, $send_path);
?>
```